# How to mapping postgresql jsonb to java object r2dbc

Tags: java, json, spring, r2dbc

I have an entity mapping with a table `pc_customer` in PostgreSQL.
I have an issue when mapping a field `jsonb` from PostgreSQL to Object in Java using R2DBC.

Here is my code:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table("pc_customer")
public class Customer extends KunlunDomain {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String secret;
    private String code;

    @Column(value = "customer_authorities")
    CustomerAuthorities customerAuthorities;
    String zaloId;

    @Data
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    public static class CustomerAuthorities implements Serializable {
        boolean importParcel = false;
        boolean printParcelStamp = false;
        boolean draftServicesEnable = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the error received:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json$JsonByteArrayInput] to type [***com.example.Customer$CustomerAuthorities]
```

Column `customer_authorities` is `jsonb`.
So what can I do to map `jsonb` to a class in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Create **BiFunctional Row Mapper** for mapping DB row with java object [On Repository]

**Example** -

```
@Autowired
private DatabaseClient databaseClient;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper
public static final BiFunction<Row, RowMetadata, Customer> customerRowMapper = (row, rowMetadata) -> Customer.builder()
          // ...rest of the field
          // call your setter fun here 
          .customerAuthorities(objectMapper.readValue(row.get("customer_authorities", String.class), Customer.CustomerAuthorities.class))
          .build();

public Flux<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
  return databaseClient
            .sql("YOUR SQL QUERY")
            .map(customerRowMapper) // here will call the biFunctional row mapper
            .all();
  }
}
```